# Encrypting XML Element

Tags: asp.net

I have created XML file called users.xml
Looks like this:

```
<Users>
  <user>
    <uin>"0012345"</uin>
    <name>black</name>
    <email>"bk@hotemail.com"</email>
    <created>"3/02/2010"</created>
  </user>
  <user>
    <uin>"123456780"</uin>
    <name>sam</name>
    <email>"sam@hotmail.com"</email>
    <created>"3/02/2010"</created>
  </user>
  <user>
    <uin>"123456799"</uin>
    <name>kblack</name>
    <email>"kblack@hotmail.com"</email>
    <created>"3/02/2010"</created>
  </user>
</Users>
```

I want to encrypt the  element.  Using code like

```
XmlElement uinelement = (XmlElement)xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Users/user/uin");
```

...encrypts only first UIN from the user.xml file.

How can I Encrypt all UIN elements?

Thank you
Kanta

Comment: The code you showed doesn't encrypt anything.  It selects the element, but does not encrypt.  

What do you really want to do?  do you want to select all the elements?  or do you want to encrypt something?  or.... what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml was not correctly encoded, so I can't see your document structure, however I would guess that using the SelectNodes() method of the XmlDocument class instead of SelectSingleNode() would do the trick.

You may also want to look at some of the Linq to XML capabilities if you need to output the transformation to a new XML doc.

Comment: Let me try SelectNodes() method instead of SelectSingleNode()

Comment: { XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
      try {xmldoc.Load("users.xml");   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  }
  TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDESkey = new tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    XmlDocument uinElem = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("users/user/uin");
    EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(xmldoc);
    //How to encrypts node rather than element ????
    byte[] encrypteduin = exml.EncryptData(uinElem, tDESkey, false);
     EncryptedData ed = new EncryptedData();

cotinution

Comment: continution
ed.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
    ed.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncTripleDESUrl);
  ed.CipherData = new CipherData();     
   ed.CipherData.CipherValue = encrypteduin;     
EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(billinguin, ed, false);
  xmldoc.Save("encrypteduser.xml");
When I choose selectNode() of XmlDocument class not sure how do change this line
byte[] encrypteduin = exml.EncryptData(uinElem, tDESkey, false);
EncryptData() is for element not for the node I think
I am following http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/21564

Comment: Thank you Ckramer, It is working now. After some modification.
Now I am working on encrypt the XML attributes of an element.

Thanks
Kanta